# What is the best way to manage a number of state of child components in parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to manage a number of child components in parent component.

However, when one of child component trigger onCheck event, all child components were re-rendered. (because handleToggleCheck function was changed.)

```js
const Parent = (props) => {
    const {codes} = props // codes is list length 1000

    const [checkedCodes, setCheckedCodes] = useState<Set<string>>(new Set())

    const handleToggleCheck = (code) => {
        if (!checkedCodes.has(code)) checkedCodes.add(code)
        else checkedCodes.delete(code)

        setCheckedCodes(new Set(checkedCodes))
    }

    return (
        codes.map(code => (
            <Child key={code} checked={checkedCodes.has(code)} onCheck={handleToggleCheck} code={code} />
        ))
    }
}

const Child = (props) => {
    const {checked, code, onCheck} = props

    return (
        <input type=“checkbox” checked={checked} onChange={() => onCheck(code)} />
    )
}
```

I tried to wrap handleToggleCheck function using useCallback, but It doesn’t work because checkedCodes re-maked when called handleToggleCheck.

```
const handleToggleCheck = useCallback((code) => {
    //…
}, [checkedCodes])
```

And I tried also use useRef instead of useState, but it doesn’t re-render child component when checkedCodes changed.

```
//…
const checkedCodes = useRef(new Set())
//…

return (
    codes.map(code => (
        <Child … checked={checkedCodes.current.has(code)} … />
    ))
)
```

What is the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to wrap handleToggleCheck function using useCallback, but It doesn’t work because checkedCodes re-maked when called handleToggleCheck.
>
> ```
>   const handleToggleCheck = useCallback((code) => {
>      //…
>   }, [checkedCodes])
> ```

You can remove checkedCodes as a dependency with a little rewriting:

```
const handleToggleCheck = useCallback((code) => {
  setCheckedCodes(prev => {
    if (!prev.has(code)) prev.add(code);
    else prev.delete(code);

    return new Set(prev);
  });
}, [])
```

However, `useCallback` alone will not prevent the children from being rendered. You will also need to use `React.memo` to tell react it should skip the component if none of its props have changed:

```
import { memo } from 'react';

const Child = memo((props) => {
  const {checked, code, onCheck} = props

  return (
    <input type=“checkbox” checked={checked} onChange={() => onCheck(code)} />
  )
})
```